# message digest hash MD5

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to get MD5 hash for the string `"password"`.

When I am using `MD5PasswordEncoder` class from Spring framework I am getting this:

> `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`

But when I am using Java's `MessageDigest` class with MD5 I am getting this:

> `9577-525990-89101-4229-12539-34-72-126-49-103`

First one is Hex and other one is Decimal. Why is there a difference? Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    PasswordEncoder pEncoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder(); 
    System.out.println(pEncoder.encodePassword("password", null));

    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update("password".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte [] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(b);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed to add a question. If the question is why are they different, my answer would be: Have you read the documentation of those 2 classes?

Comment: Asides from the values being *very* different, what's the problem?

Comment: yes question is why are they different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your print function. The following code prints the same value as your Spring application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update("password".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest));

  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Prints:

> `5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    for (byte b : digest) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
```

you will get

```
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to do with the way in which the output from the Java MessageDigest is being converted to a String.

Try

```
System.out.print(new String(org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex.encode(digest)));
```

to convert the bytes to hex.